# Inquiring a specific DataGridView column based on CurrentRow

Tags: c#, windows, datagridview

I am using a .NET 4.5 DataGridView in C# (Visual Studio 2010) with several columns (Index, PosX, PosY, ...). I fill it with several rows of custom data like this:

```
string[] row = new string[MyDataGridView.ColumnCount];
for (int i = 0; i < NumResults; i++)
    row = new string[] { i.ToString(), PosXArray[i].ToString(), PosYArray[i].ToString(), ... }
MyDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```

Each row holds information for one object, identified by an "Index" column value. When the user selects a row I want to know which object was selected. I am using the "SelectionChanged" event to request the CurrentRow like this:

```
int CurrentRow = -1;
private void MyDataGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MyDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index != CurrentRow)
        // Access the data over MyDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index

    CurrentRow = MyDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index;
}
```

This works as long as the CurrentRow index is the same as the "Index" value on column 1. However the user could sort the datagrid in a different way for example based on the "Position X" column.

So I want to know how I can access the value of a specific column based only on the row index.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution like this:

```
string ObjectIndex = MyDataGridView.Rows[MyDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```